# Finding English Letters in a multilingual document

Tags: regular-expressions, characters

I have a document mainly Persian with English/French/German characters here and there. I want to append a command before Latin word(s) and a `}` at the end. Do you think it could be done in emacs?

Suppose there's an English sentence for example *Welcome to Emacs* I want it to become `\lr{Welcome to Emacs}`.

*It is a markdown document which in turn is going to be converted to Latex. `\lr{}` is a local command for a Persian package which renders non-RTL words and sentences correctly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[:ascii:]` [char class](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html) can help.

`C-M-%` to query replace regexp `\(\ *\)\([[:ascii:]]*[a-zA-z]\)` with `\1\\lr{\2}`

If new line character must not be included into sentence then change regexp to replace to `\(\ *\)\([a-zA-z ]*[a-zA-z]\)`

Comment: Thanks. It's ok just a minor issue. There's one instance of *This is sentence, 111, 111. non-ascii*, is there any way to include *, 111, 111.* ?

Comment: And what's this `[a-zA-z]`?

Comment: `\(\ *\)\([[:ascii:]]*[a-zA-z0-9,.]\)`. `a-z` it's a character range. More info [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html)

Comment: No, I meant what's its meaning here?

Comment: Group 2 select all ascii characters and final characters range must be character and not space

Comment: I should test every single character reg-exp in your line to understand how it does what I want. Thanks.